# Certificate must have a fully-qualified domain name, a supported signature, and a supported key size

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I am trying to add certificate listner against a certificate using following code

```
                const listenerBody = {
                Certificates: [
                    {
                        CertificateArn: certificate.certificate_arn
                    },
                ],
                ListenerArn: httpsListnerArn
            }
elbv2.addListenerCertificates(listenerBody, async function (err, data) {}
```

But I am getting following error

UnsupportedCertificate: The certificate 'arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:557863456534:certificate/7accec1c-57df-4c6f-a5c5-3f76b1fa9f92' must have a fully-qualified domain name, a supported signature, and a supported key size.

Answer (score 23):

Error messages can be a bit misleading at times. You may receive this error if the certificate is still pending validation. If the certificate was recently added to AWS Certificate Manager, make sure that it has been validated. Certificates will not be available for use unless you are able to validate that you own or control the domain(s). You can validate ownership using email or DNS.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was the timing after cert creation and validation.
I needed to sleep about 20 seconds for the process to go smoothly.
I slept 10 seconds for starters, only worked when I waited 20, so somewhere between 10-20 seconds the Cert becomes detectable on the LBs.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where and how you implemented the sleep?

Comment: Hey,
Sorry for the delayed response on this. I am actually using Celery to do this, and I just have a celery task retry with a back-off timer on a specific Exception.
I keep on checking to see if the operation is executed, if not, i raise an exception and the task retries.

Something like this:

@app.task(
    autoretry_for=(CertNotValidated, DnsRecordsNotReady,),
    retry_backoff=30,
    retry_backoff_max=1800,
    max_retries=50)
def create_aws_dns_records:
    code_here
    if result is False:
        raise CertNotValidated
    rest of code